# PVS Studio: Comments in autogenerated files. MVC, VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, pvs-studio

PVS Studio Free version is asking to add the license comment in autogenerated files

It is a local net core 6 mvc c# 8.0 in VS 2022, Windows 10, closed source, independent developer
Final project (validate edi files)  will be free to use

I have added the required comments in the top of the autogenerated files
Just wondering if this a minor bug in PVS Studio?
They are all *.cs files though

Ran the PVS check for entire solution in VS IDE to add comments in needed source files
Didn't expect autogenerated file pop up

Thanks /Peter

Answer (score 1):

Since autogenerated files appear after the project is built, they lack a comment for free use. Analysis of such files makes no sense, so PVS-Studio removes autogenerated files (for example, those with the g.cs extension) from analysis. I think that in your case, the analyzer did not remove it because the file has a standard extension. Is it possible to understand that the file is generated automatically (e.g., maybe there are some comments in the code)? Perhaps you could send us a synthetic example of a project that has autogenerated files like yours, and we could explore the possibility of excluding such files from the analysis.

If you are sure that a comment has been added for each non-autogenerated file, you can simply disable this message:

[image: pic].